# Is there a way for setting a shorter timeout in an ssh command?

Tags: ssh, timeout

I am writing a Bash script that performs several commands on remote machines via SSH.

The problem is when one of those machines is unreachable, I would like the script to skip and move on instead, it stays stuck until and after a long time it gives a connection timed out.

Is there a way for setting a shorter timeout in an `ssh` command?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To specify the timeout (in seconds), use the `ConnectTimeout` option as specified in the [`ssh_config` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config):

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 user@remotehost
```

To specify the timeout for all hosts, add this configuration to a wildcard stanza in your ssh config file, typically `~/.ssh/config` for personal configuration, or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to apply systemwide:

```
Host *
    ConnectTimeout 10
```